# JavaScript in Node.js scoping

Tags: javascript, node.js, scoping

I do have an issue with scoping variables in Javascript (Node.js / Express)

Can someone please explain to me why is the "out" variable not being scoped to the last line in the following script?

```
exports.last = function(req, res){
  var out = [];
  var q = Point.find({ token: req.params.token }).distinct('key');
  q.exec(function (err, keys, count) {
    keys.forEach(function(k) {
      var q2 = Point.findOne({ token: req.params.token, key: k }).sort({time:-1})
      q2.exec(function(err, p, count) {
        out.push({ a: Date.parse(p.time), b: parseFloat(p.val) });
      });
    })
    console.log(out);
  })
  res.json(out);
};
```

Comment: it is "scoped", but `res.json` is likely executed before `console.log`

Comment: Looks like the everyday async question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: @elclanrs you are right; I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commentors are correct: this is not a scoping issue, but a consequence of the asynchronous nature of JavaScript.  Imagine you could assign an "step number" to every line of code.  Here is a simplified view of your code (the numbers are step numbers, as the JavaScript engine executes things, NOT line numbers):

```
1   var thing = [];
2   q2.exec(function(){
        // some stuff happens
15      thing.push('hello!');
    });
3   console.log(thing);  // still empty!
```

See how the flow goes 1, 2, 3, skipping over the function call in `q2.exec`?  That's because `q2.exec` is *asynchronous*: you're saying "whenever `q2.exec` is done, call this function."  You don't know when it's going to be done.  So it proceeds on to step 3, and then it does other stuff...eventually, `q.exec` finishes, and it executes your function (in this fictional example, it's step 15).

Hope that clarifies things.

As far as how to *fix* it, you'll have to either employ callbacks or, more likely in this case, use "promises".  Why promises in this case?  Because you're calling `q2.exec` a bunch of times, and I assume you only want to log to the console after *all* the `q2.exec` calls have completed.  So you could do something like this (using the Q promises library):

```
var Q = require('q');  // this has nothing to do with your 'q2'
var promises = [];
var thing = [];
stuff.forEach(function(x,i){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    q2.exec(function(){
        thing.push('hello ' + i);
        deferred.resolve();
    });
    promises.push(deferred.promise);
});
Q.all(promises).then(function(){
    // all calls to q2.exec now complete
    console.log(thing);
});
```

Comment: Promises are being added to pure JavaScript. Just wanted to get that out there.

Comment: One day, yes!  It'll probably be available in Node soon, but you won't be able to rely on it in browsers without polyfilling for another couple of years, probably :(

Comment: I just read a good article about that exact topic, incidentally: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: Chrome lets you enable built-in Promises already, but it is still experimental.

Comment: I don't even have to enable them...they're there by default in Chrome (32).  I hear Firefox has them too.  My point, though, is if you're developing "real world" website, you have to be prepared for people to use older browsers.  Sad but true.